# Glassfish 3.1.2's JDBCRealm has a new Password Encryption Algorithm field. What is it for?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

The Glassfish JDBC realm features several different properties you can set.

I am interested in the **Digest Algorithm** and **Password Encryption Algorithm** properties (that's how they show up in the admin console).

The second one is new as of Glassfish 3.1.2 as near as I can tell.

I have [consulted the official Glassfish 3.1.1 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html#ggmww) but it does not address the new property, and does not really explain what the first property is used for.

There is a [documentation bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17796) that references a bug number (13363269) that must point to a defunct bug system because I can't find the bug to which it refers.  This phantom bug presumably details what the **Password Encryption Algorithm** property is for, but alas seems to be lost to the mists of time.

From the command line, the property is named (improbably): `digestrealm-password-enc-algorithm`.  It looks like this will live on next to the `digest-algorithm` property.

I attempted to read the [source code, but the `JDBCRealm.java` file appears to be missing](http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk/main/nucleus/security/core/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/realm/jdbc?rev=52693) although I am doubtlessly simply looking in the wrong place.  A prior copy that I found does not reference the property anywhere.

**What are these two properties for?**  I have a hazy sense that together they ensure that if I use the realm to login with a plaintext password I can somehow delegate the hashing-and-comparing operations to the realm, provided of course that the hashes used to store the original password and the hashes used on the incoming password were calculated the same way.

The manual also indicates that if I want to use digest authentication that I should be specifying the `jdbcDigestRealm` JAAS context.  If I don't want to use digest authentication, then I should be specifying the `jdbcRealm` JAAS context.  To my eyes, this looks like yet another place where I am effectively specifying what kinds of hashing algorithms are involved.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this (related issue) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067410/glassfish-3-1-2-jdbcrealm-configuration/20714695#20714695) - Glassfish 3.1.2 JDBCRealm configuration.

In short, the password encryption field does not seem to be mandatory at all anymore - so just storing passwords as SHA 256 hashes should work well enough.